# Add table of contents to existing PDF

Tags: linux, pdf, table-of-contents

I have several pdfs, of which my pdf-viewer can show the outline, like in this example:

[image]

While this is a great feature, there are unfortunately some pdfs, that have no such feature implemented!

[image]

Only bookmarks can be added, but for me that is not an option, because it‘s a viewer-dependent solution. For some books, it would be very helpful to  have such an outline, so i thought about adding that myself, but i couldn‘t find any program, script or different solution except for Adobe Acrobat Pro, which is much too expensive for me.

Does anyone know something that suits my problem? A Linux solution would be prefered.